# How to make fade-in/fade-out popup window?

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, fade

How do you make a notification form pop up in the corner of the screen and then fade away, on top of all other apps, like they do in MS Outlook for new emails, or IMs to notify you that one of your contacts has just signed in?  Is there anything native to C# that does this?  3rd party control?  Or some open source code that will achieve all the fancy special effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx

Messenger Style

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to  show some Information to user then..What you are talking about is called Ballon Tip in notification area....You can do this with Notify Icon Control ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx )

use the `BallonTipText` property to set the Text you want to show..

You dont need any thing like Interop to do this..

Comment: +1 As it turns out, this is the solution I'm going to use, because it's the simplest.  But answer credit to @WraithNath, because TaskBarNotifier is the best answer to the question I actually asked.  Thanks!

Comment: @Shaul.. i have no prob.. @Wraithnath's answer is also good..  we should promote new user's contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a managed way to do this, but you can use interop and do a [layered window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). [UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

in Simple Way you can set `TopMost` and `Opacity` of your form in the Load Event

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.Opacity = 0;
```

and Change your Opacity with a timer. dont know whether its a good way